# cordova-google-plus throwing error code 10

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, google-plus-signin

I am stuck in a very popular issue in the Cordova google-plus plugin. The issue is whenever I include this `'webClientId': '******.apps.googleusercontent.com',` I am getting `error: 10` and without that `webClientId` inclusion I am getting data that doesn't provide tokenID but I need **tokenID** so I am passing **client ID** generated in Google Developers console as a value to `webClientID`.

I have seen articles saying that **SHA1** might be wrong, so I checked and it turns out that both **app-debug.apk** SHA-1 and the project in the Google Developers console SHA-1 are the same.

I have followed [this article](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus#5-installation-phonegap-build) for implementation and I have not included the project in firebase. I know something is wrong with my client ID but I am not able to figure it out. I have tried reinstalling the plugin but it didn't work.

**NOTE**: If an empty object that is passed as 1st argument to `googleplus.login()` returns data without any error.

```js
  loginGoogle() {
    console.log('clicked')
  window['plugins'].googleplus.login(
      {
        'webClientId': '*******.apps.googleusercontent.com', 
      },
      function (obj) {
        console.log('data:', obj);
      },
      function (msg) {
        console.log('error: ' + msg);
      }
  );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Google Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/) has changed its process of getting the CLIENT_ID. We need to create an "OAuth consent screen" and then create `credentials` where you will get the CLIENT_ID. Now the answer to my question is while creating credentials, as the 1st step, there will be a dropdown for selecting `application type` and select `web` for Cordova, Ionic (I am not sure for react-native and native Android) and complete the process.

Then you will get a CLIENT_ID aka WEB_CLIENT_ID but if you choose Android in `application type` and the same CLIENT_ID aka ANDRIOD_CLIENT_ID. The problem lies in selecting `application type`. I have answers people are just mentioning WEB_CLIENT_ID.

Comment: can you please share that solution you have for WEB_CLIENT_ID?